# get application path in asp.net vnext

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-core

I've been trying to open a file in asp.net 5 and have not been having a lot of success.

In the past you used `Server.MapPath` or `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`. They are both gone in the OWIN based framework.

There is a `HostingEnvironment` class but it's in the `System.Aspnet` but it needs to be initialized by the hosting environment (it no longer has a static member for `ApplicationPhysicalPath` but I'm guessing the `WebRoot` member does that now. The problem is I can't find a reference to it anywhere.

I've also looked at `Context.GetFeature<>` but it doesn't seem to have any feature that would show the application path, just request and response related info. The code listing the features can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Owin/OwinFeatureCollection.cs).

`<snark>`Is the ability to work with files a discontinued feature in ASP.NET?`</snark>`

There is also the possibility that I can't [brain](http://weknowmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/i-cannot-brain-today-i-has-the-dumb-cat.jpg) very well right now and missed something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get it from the `ApplicationBasePath` property of `Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment` serivce.

Example: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/9f1cb655f6bb1fa0ce1c1e3782c43a2d45ca4e37/test/WebSites/FilesWebSite/Controllers/DownloadFilesController.cs#L28

Comment: `IApplicationEnvironment` is now in `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions` namespace

Comment: IApplicationEnvironment is now IHostingEnvironment in ASP.NET Core 1.0. More info here - https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html

Answer (score 6):

There are two approaches now:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;

public Startup(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    // approach 1
    var path01 = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;

    // approach 2
    var path02 = appEnv.ApplicationBasePath;
}
```